# Best scenario to block internet load certain ip/host and Injected http Ads Script?

Tags: http

Im sorry if the question is to broad or unspecified ..but the situation is

Im using cable internet with Huawei HG8245A as a router (ISP company Hard coded The router with custom firmware so we cant go to advanced setting such as firewall,bandwith management etc, we also cant switch to different router as they didn't tell us the PON password)

MY isp is using filter to block access to certain bad site (adult,gambling) 
the problem is lots of good website also caught in this filter where they automatically redirect to specified host owned also by my isp ,where from here they put with a loads of ads ,not only this they also injected http traffic with Javascript ads

the complete ip and injected ads code can be view in here
https://github.com/sentabi/telkom/blob/master/internet-positif.md

problem comes when this host seems to be down as they mostly hit by huge amount of traffic which end up our browser cannot finish to load any website

If we use desktop or laptop i can use software such as dnscrypt to bypass this ,but i also shared this connection via Wifi (for Mobile phone INternet, PS4 access etc) where this ads is still injected ..for logging on paid licensed software mostly failed with notification that our request has been modified

im aiming to block request for specific ip/domain listed above so it wont load on our http traffic

also can't switch isp ,either our area isnt covered by other isp or the monthly contract were to expensive

Any suggestion?

Comment: Change your ISP.

Answer (score 1):

There are ad blocking hardware devices that sit right after your router and before the rest of your internal network.  You can purchase a cheap router that supports DD-WRT and then turn that into an ad [blocker.](https://www.google.com/amp/s/lifehacker.com/5680670/turn-your-dd-wrt-enabled-router-into-a-whole-house-ad-blocker/amp) . Alternatively, you can use a Raspberry Pi to do [ad blocking](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/adblock-everywhere-raspberry-pi-hole-way/) as well.